# How Do I Sync My Exchange Calendar in Ubuntu (Thunderbird / Lightning)?

Tags: thunderbird, ms-exchange

Coming from a Microsoft Windows Environment, what is the best way to sync one's calendar on Ubuntu / Thunderbird / Lightning?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The [ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar](https://github.com/ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar/releases) plugin for Thunderbird seems to solve this problem gracefully.  Here are some steps to get you going:

1. Install the [Lightning Plugin](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/calendar/) for Thunderbird.
2. Download the ms-exchange calendar plugin from [ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar](https://github.com/ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar/releases).  The *.xpi plugin may be inside a zip file.  Save the file to your Downloads folder (or elsewhere).
3. In Thunderbird, click menu-->Add-ons
4. Click the icon to install an add-on from a local file (fig 1 below).
5. Once the plugins are all installed and Thunderbird has re-started, open the calendar tab in Thunderbird.  Right click in the calendars section and choose "new calendar".
6. Choose "On the network"
7. Choose Microsoft Exchange.
8. Choose a name for the calendar.
9. Now the tricky part.  I could not get the autodiscovery feature to work, but if you enter the correct server url and username, you're good to go.  For office 365, the url is:  https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx.  See figure 2 below.
10. Click "Check Server and Mailbox".  If you got the server and username right, the folder base input should appear With a Next button (figure 3).  Click Next.  Everything seems to work from this point.  Good luck!

**Figure 1 -- Install a the downloaded exchange plugin**

[image: Install the locally saved exchange add-on]

**Figure 2 -- Configure the Exchange Settings**

[image: Configure the exchange settings]

**Figure 3 -- After clicking "Check Server and Mailbox", the folder base input appears with a "Next" button**

[image: Correctly configured exchange server -- yay]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the step-by-step instructions! It's working perfectly.

Comment: It worked, I just needed to manually enter the server URL (https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx)

Comment: When I try it, my server url is pre-entered and greyed out and I don't get a "check server and mailbox". http://askubuntu.com/questions/663223/is-it-possible-to-use-microsoft-exchange-calendar-with-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment957161_663223

Comment: @Programmer400 - Is it really greyed out or is it just placeholder text that you can overtype?   Fooled me for a couple of mins (on the Windows version).

Comment: I have written a tutorial with even more pictures: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/06/03/thunderbird-mit-office365-verbinden/ For those that need it.

Comment: This also works for a shared calendar as well. Just set the email address to none and fill out the primary email of the shared calendar. I do believe your Lightning needs your primary exchange account to be active under accounts. I was not prompted for a password when I added another employee's shared calendar.

Comment: The github address has been changed to https://github.com/ExchangeCalendar/exchangecalendar/releases

Comment: I had to download the latest beta (beta 5) of version 4.0.0 to get it to work. I had the exact same issues with connecting as was described in an issue-thread from a year ago, so I'm assuming Microsoft updates the API breaking backwards compatibility now and then…

Answer (score 3):

ExchangeCalendar did work - until TB60. :-(

Now I rely on TbSync, it does a decent job.

https://github.com/jobisoft/TbSync

See the manual:
https://github.com/jobisoft/TbSync/wiki/How-to-get-started

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on Linux, and here's how I did it. On Windows the files are located in a different spot (Google will tell you where), but the overall method should still work with DropBox, SeaFile, or equivalent data-syncing services.

I use Thunderbird/Lightning as my email/calendar client on my main computer (Thinkpad W541, Ubuntu Unity, 16.04) and my travel Chromebook (Acer C720, Ubuntu XFCE, 16.04), and I wanted to regularly sync the calendar data between both machines.  Suggestions online often mention Google Calendar, but I'd rather use open-source tools (that I control) to do the job.  I use SeaFile (a FOSS DropBox equivalent) to sync folders & files between my machines.

**Step 1**:  On my new Chromebook, I copy over my entire Thunderbird directory:
`rsync -zarv user@thinkpad:~/.thunderbird/  ~/.thunderbird/`
Then, I install Thunderbird and open it: presto, all my accounts, old emails, and (most importantly) calendar events are accessible. Great!

**Step 2**: It looks like all relevant Thunderbird data are stored in ~/.thunderbird/blah.default/, with calendar data in ~/.thunderbird/blah.default/calendar-data/.  On the Chromebook, I create a new calendar event, save it, and see that ~/.thunderbird/blah.default/calendar-data/local.sqlite has increased in size and has a newer "last-modified" timestamp.  I conclude that local.sqlite contains all relevant calendar data.

**Step 3**: I close Thunderbird on both machines, then use SeaFile to sync the entire calander-data/ folder on both.  I see that the newer filesize and timestamp have successfully synced on the Thinkpad. I open Thunderbird on the new machine, and there in the calendar is my new event.  Success!

**Drawbacks**: 
The main drawback seems to be that if Thunderbird is open on both machines and either calendar is edited, syncing the calendar-data files sometimes causes the other machine's Thunderbird to crash.  They just weren't built to handle that sort of I/O.  But otherwise: it works great!