# Is it possible to use Microsoft Exchange Calendar with Ubuntu?

Tags: calendar, ms-exchange

I use MS exchange webmail and I have a web calendar there where my meetings are booked. Now I'd like to know a way where I can get a popup reminder when a meeting is (or some minutes before) that has focus. Now I only get the popups for meeting if I'm on the webpage for my webmail / calendar.

I would like functionality similar to desktop slack where I get a popup reminder when I get a message regardless of which window I have open.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I tried a number of plugins including thunderbird 31.8.0 and lightning 3.3.3 with the exchange provider plugin, then nothing is possible and I can't even add a server url.

[image][image]

Comment: I don't use Exchange, so I won't add this as an answer, but you should try Evolution. I think it should be able to do what you want, and a lot more.

Comment: Also note that thunderbird has an Calendar addon called lightning that - at the top of my head - can also do what you want.

Comment: I tried lightning with this plugin https://github.com/Ericsson/exchangecalendar/releases but nothing is possible when I installed it. It doesn't work (t-bird 31.8.0)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/562498/how-do-i-sync-my-exchange-calendar-in-ubuntu-thunderbird-lightning works on one of our systems :P

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the link. It looks similar but my server url is greyed out so I can't enter a server url. I'm trying to investigate why it happens.

Comment: Means you are missing a package or a service that is not running (it should get active when everything is working on "our" side).

Comment: @Rinzwind Please can you help me guess what I'm missing. I don't have a good ideas what to do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem. If you just start typing, the greyed out URL will disappear and you will be able to enter your own URL.